# how to bind two-way radio button in angular 2

Tags: angular

Here is my code, In last name i used ngModel so its working two way data binding but in radio button how I used ngModel for two way data binding.

```
   <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !lastname.valid }">
                    <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" [(ngModel)]="employee.last_name" #lastname="ngModel" required />
                    <div *ngIf="f.submitted && !lastname.valid" class="help-block">Last Name is required</div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Gender:</label> &nbsp;
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="optradio" [checked]="employee.gender == 'Male'" >Male
                </label>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                     <input type="radio" name="optradio" [checked]="employee.gender == 'Female'" >Female
                </label>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For two way data binding its as same as all others use this syntax `[(ngModel)]`

Replace your code block with below:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Gender:</label> 
    &nbsp;

    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="optradio" value='Male' [(ngModel)]="employee.gender" >Male
    </label>

    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="optradio" value='Female' [(ngModel)]="employee.gender" >Female
    </label>

</div>
```

Comment: @Krunal, will you please accept the answer and also upvote it?

Comment: sorry... I forgot that. now check .;)

Comment: my account is banned for ask question.. help plz @ Vivek Doshi

Comment: Why What happen?

Comment: Then delete those questions

Comment: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. I am stuck at this error from the last 2 days

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
 <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Gender:</label> &nbsp;
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" [(ngModel)]="employee.gender"
[value]='Male' [checked]="employee.gender == 'Male'" >Male
                </label>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                     <input type="radio" name="gender" [(ngModel)]="employee.gender"
[value]='Female' [checked]="employee.gender == 'Female'" >Female
                </label>
                </div>
```

Also, you forgot to add the `[value]` property in your inputs and change the `name` of the `input` to `gender`